# Yii framework 2.0 multiple paginations on one page

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

Working with Yii framework 2.0 I tried to use the pagination feature and linkpager widget, following Yii documentation.

Below is my controller.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Country::find();

    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 5,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);

    $countries = $query->orderBy('name')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'countries' => $countries,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
```

In my index view, I use the following code.

```
<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Now I want to add one more pagination feature and LinkPager widget for another model ***City***. In the actionIndex() method I follow the existing code, just create an object of ***City*** and an object of ***new Pagination*** and return it to the view. In the view I include LinkPager widget once again with another pagination variable ***$paginationCity***. When I click on a pagination number I saw the query string ***page=xx*** in the URL. I notice that it is being used for both models ***Country*** and ***City***. How can I use multiple pagination on one same page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by changing [pageParam](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageParam-detail) property of `Pagination` class:

```
$cityPagination = new Pagination([
    ...    
    'pageParam' => 'city-page',
]);
```

Comment: Hi, i have three pagination i a single page! After setting different pageParam for each one pagination is not working! can you please help?

Comment: `Pagination::pageSizeParam` is also useful when dealing with multiple paginations. `pageSizeParam` is the variable in the Url holding the number of results per page, default 'per-page' 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$pageSizeLimit-detail